# jQuery text() ignores <br /> with nl2br

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm having issues when retrieving, by json, text information and want to display well formated into a `<p>` tag.

Imagine the following text:

> Description: Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.
>
> See: https://api.jquery.com/get/

As you can see it has three lines.

When I directly write into the `<p>` tag by PHP it works.

```
<p>echo nlbr2($comment);</p>
```

But what I want is to retrieve this text by JSON and with jQuery send that text to the `<p>` tag.

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'comment' => nl2br($comment)));
```

And the output of the answer is:

```
{"status":1,"comment":"Description: Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.<br \/>\r\nSee: https:\/\/api.jquery.com\/get\/"}
```

In the jQuery side I do the following:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);

$('p').text(json.comment);
```

But when looking at the text of the `<p>` tag, it shows:

[image]

I've also tried to replace, but ain't working.

```
json.comment.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
```

[image]

Comment: try using `$('p').text(json.comment);`

Comment: Your comment is html. `.text()` creates (or updates) a text node, meaning your html tags will be displayed as `<`, `p`, `>`, etc.. characters. try `.html()` instead. that also means your `<br>` is treated as 4 separate characters, not not a "line break".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.text()` use `.html()`

```
$('p').html(json.comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

text() always represent html tags as string. Using html() instead will be the best option if you want to use html tags.